# XCode 9 beta showing error when app launch

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to open my existing project in XCode 9 Beta version. Code is compile without any error, however when simulator showing warning in alert when app launch.

Please let me know what is going wrong.

> Failed to change owner of
>   file:///Users/stiga/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2A6099D8-6743-4551-AE73-CE7AFCAEE9FE/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.opEVCA/TestWifog.app:
>   Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=4 "Failed to remove ACL"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdb12706dc0 {Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"
>   UserInfo={SourceFileLine=392, NSLocalizedDescription=open of
>   /Users/stiga/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2A6099D8-6743-4551-AE73-CE7AFCAEE9FE/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.opEVCA/TestWifog.app/GoogleSignIn.bundle/ar.lproj/GoogleSignIn.strings
>   failed: Permission denied, FunctionName=-[MIFileManager
>   removeACLAtPath:isDir:error:]}}, FunctionName=-[MIFileManager
>   removeACLAtPath:isDir:error:], SourceFileLine=392,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to remove ACL}

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems that the GoogleSignIn.bundle is not configured correctly. For me the permissions dening is for Roboto-Bold.ttf, but same ACL issue.

Comment: Any Idea about solving this problem.

Comment: Still searching how to fix it, I'm trying to see what happens in a new project having GoogleSignIn added using CocoaPods. Anyway, this always happens with Google pods, they are configured horribly :/

Comment: Might be google update this pretty soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem happens when files in your target are marked read-only. One common cause is a copy-files script where the files it is copying are read-only.

You can try adding a `chmod u+w` command to the script to ensure the files are read-write after being copied into the target.

For Cocoapods, you can try `chmod -R u+w /path/to/your/project/Pods` to make all files in the pods subdirectory writable.