# Unable to install app in simulator Xcode 9 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9-beta, xcode9

I downloaded Xcode 9 beta recently, and when I tried to run my app in the simulator it is not getting installed. I am getting this error in my Xcode every time I try to run the app.

> This app was unable to be installed.

[image]

The application used to work in Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? If so, what were the steps to be able to install the application again?

Comment: @rodalfus I didn't find any solution for this, I removed Xcode 9 and reinstalled Xcode 8.3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode 9 beta showing error when app launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517741/xcode-9-beta-showing-error-when-app-launch)

Answer (score 23):

Unfortunately, the error message doesn’t explain *why* the install failed.  You can take a look at ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log to see if the rest of the error message is there with more info.  If not, you should check out the sim device’s system log:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app # if you haven’t already
xcrun simctl spawn booted log show
```

You can use `--predicate` to filter that down a bit.

Comment: Ok, I will check that. Thanks for help.

Comment: Turns out my app extension did not have a valid `CFBundleVersion` string. Thanks for this tip.

Comment: In my case I didn't have matching bundle identifier for watch and extension. I have renamed original app's one some time ago, but forgot to rename in other targets.
Command that I have used was: 
    `xcrun simctl spawn booted log show | grep "This app was unable to be installed."`

Comment: This should be accepted answer, since it's the only way to figure out the actual reason for the error

Answer (score 11):

Late answer but might be that can be useful for others. I just get a project with existing watch-kit and custom keyboard code. After change the identifier i got the same error and i spend 1 day to find out why that happens.

I checked everything of bundle id and all version. then i do global search in xcode with old identifier and i found that following.

[image]

Here in both .plist file have old **WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier** so after i update it with new manually application run again.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

> IF YOU ARE JUST CHANGE IDENTIFIER FROM GENERAL TAB THAT DOES NOT MEAN IT UPDATE AT ALL. KINDLY CHECK WITH ALL POSSIBLE PLACES BY SEARCH AND REPLACE IT WITH NEW IDENTIFIER.

```
XCODE VERSIO: Version 9.0 (9A235)
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue and a quick click on [Product > Clean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weReK.png) did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CocoaPods in your project please have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44533287/221194

Changing the status of the pods subdirectory helped me with my project.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when installing my App on the IOS simulator (with Xcode 9).

I found the issue (at least for my case), it was due to an unauthorized key (Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description) in the info.plist of the Watch App.

I have moved this key to the info.plist of the WatchKit Extension and now the App installs again.

I hope it will help others people having the same issue.

Comment: works for me. thank you. it seems like my usage has not be added

Answer (score 0):

change deployment target as per requirement.
**select project > GENERAL > DEPLOYMENT TARGET**
also check ios version of your device

Comment: Deployment Target is ios 9 and simulator is running on ios 11 beta.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Log shows it's an error caused by Google Signin:

```
FunctionName=-[MobileInstallationHelperService stageItemAtURL:completion:], SourceFileLine=392, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f891e9a1270 {Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=4 "Failed to remove ACL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to remove ACL, FunctionName=-[MIFileManager _removeACLAtPath:isDir:error:]
```

However it works on iOS 9 & 10 simulator.

Comment: Then how did you solved the problem for iOS 11 simulator?

Comment: The iOS 10 simulator give me more meaningful error message.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and I was using Cocoapods in my project and for me help just update pods.

Comment: My pods are all updated but I am still not able to install the app.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue in Xcode 9.0 beta 5 after renaming a project that contained an iOS and watchOS app.  To fix, I recreated the iOS target.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be triggered by multiple things however if you take a look at the logs at `~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log` and it states an error that reads :

> NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb51c271ee0 Could not hardlink copy /originPath
>   to /destinationPath

it's possible that your Build number in your Project Target's settings is set to empty.

Go to `Project Target > Identity > Build` and set a Build number. You'll have to uninstall the the app in the simulator and re-install it before installing updated versions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the bundle identifier to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on XCode 9.3.1 when I wanted to add google map framework to my project manually.

To fix the problem I remove the google frameworks from Embedded binaries...

[image]