# iOS Xcode 9.2 App not run on simulator: "This app could not be installed at this time."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

[image]

Reset the simulator:

- Hardware -> Erase All content and settings...
- Clean my project:

still getting an alert message from Xcode 9.2 when I run the application on the simulator.

Comment: Delete app if exist in simulator -> Quit simulator -> Clean the project & run again

Comment: done all this things Delete App as well as reset simulator and also,Clean and Build project but not able to run.

Comment: quit xcode  restart your mac and check

Comment: quit xcode restart mac twice time but still getting same issue.

Comment: did u check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/44867510/5362916

Comment: @UmaMadhavi yes check this link as well but not getting any result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162079/discussion-between-pratik-panchal-and-uma-madhavi).

Answer (score 0):

try to clean your project

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

OR

1. Check simulator logs, if its printing something useful. First, select
   simulator then from menu option open Debug -> Open System Logs.
2. Make sure only 1 simulator is running.
3. Delete the older version of app from the simulator.

This should fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

1) Install the latest version of Xcode and make sure your XCode should be in Applications.

2) Delete the derived data from path

```
/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

3)  Clean your project using the below commands:

```
shift+cmd+K

shift+opt+cmd+K
```

4) Restart your system.

5) Run the project.