# This app could not be installed at this time. Could not hardlink copy

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Note that I have already googled this issue a lot and tried many solutions mentioned below.

When trying to build and run my iOS app in Simulator it fails and gives me this error:

```
This app could not be installed at this time.
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Could not install at this time.
Recovery Suggestion: Could not hardlink copy ... to ... with manifest ...

Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 8
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[MIInstallableBundlePatch _applyDeltaPatchWithError:]";
    LegacyErrorString = PackagePatchFailed;
    SourceFileLine = 113;
}
```

**I have already tried:**

- Erasing content and settings from simulator
- Cleaning build folder
- Cleaning Derived Data
- Reinstalling cocoapods
- and many more ...

I have not changed the Build version or anything like that.

**My observations:**

- When I delete the app, the first build and run works as usual
- If I do not edit the code, the subsequent runs work too
- If I edit any file even by adding comments, it gives me the error described above
- Works fine on a real device
- I have added some files (.json) to my project recently
- I have already experienced this issue with a different project when copying files from another project. I had to start over.
- When I edit a file from my project and try to run it it fails. However after reinstalling the app I can edit the file without problems
- **Switching build scheme to Release from Debug seems to help temporarily**

**Some information:**

- macOS Version 10.15.6 (Build 19G73)
- Xcode 11.6 (16141)
- Using cocoapods

**Any help is highly appreciated**

Comment: You didn't say you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517741/xcode-9-beta-showing-error-when-app-launch Try it.

Comment: Thanks @matt for the comment but it doesn't seem to have helped.